# "write error: stdout" when calling "make" from Makefile

Tags: makefile

This is my `Makefile`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS = -e -o pipefail -c 

env:
    make -version | head -1
```

This is what I'm getting on Ubuntu 20.04.3:

```
make -version | head -1
GNU Make 4.2.1
make[1]: write error: stdout
make: *** [Makefile:4: env] Error 1
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see this problem with GNU make 4.3, so I guess something was changed there to allow this to work.

To fix it you can try changing your rule to this:

```
env:
        make -version | cat | head -1
```

The error is because the `head` program closes its stdin when it's read the first line, then make complains because it fails to write to its stdout (because it was closed).

By introducing the `cat` here, the `cat` reads all the input from `make` without closing the pipe so make doesn't get any error.

PS. You should always, always use the variable `$(MAKE)` when invoking a sub-make, never the hardcoded `make`.

Comment: Same error here with `cat` (exit status 141). Probably `cat` that itself closes its `stdin` before `make` wrote its output. It looks like a race condition because it sometimes fails, sometimes not. Replacing `cat` by `{ sleep 1; cat; }` seems to solve it. Or, maybe more elegant, `head -1 < <($(MAKE) -version)`.

Comment: Or, maybe even better, `{ make -version ||:; } | head -1`.

Comment: The fancy `<(...)` won't work unless you force `SHELL = /bin/bash` as that's not a feature of the POSIX shell.

Comment: Sure. I should have mentioned it. But as the OP already states `SHELL = /bin/bash` and all this is about the `pipefail` bash option...

Comment: for me the upper is not working, instead just pipe stderr `make --version 2>/dev/null | head -n1`